# Create proxy for a interface, which could inject by @Autowired, proxy invokes different implement by key parameter

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, reflection, inject

I want to define a annotation like @PlatformRelated, once it is marked in a interface, there will be a proxy bean at spring context, and this proxy bean should be @Priority.I want this proxy could invoke different implement according to key parameter @KeyPrameter.And I still wanna use spring features like @Async,@Trasaction,etc... at my Implement1 and Implement2.

```
@PlatformRelated
interface MyInterface {
   method(@KeyPrameter String parameter);
}

@Component
class Implement1 implements MyInterface {
   method(String parameter){
       //do something 111
   }
}

@Component
class Implement2 implements MyInterface {
   method(String parameter){
       //do something  222
   }
}

@Service
class BusinessService{
    @Autowired
    private MyInterface myInterface;

    public void doSomething() {
        myInterface.method("key1");
        //Implement1 work
        myInterface.method("key2");
        //Implement2 work
    }
}
```

Do you guys have some good idea to complete it?

Comment: Would you like to create a proxy on bean for every interface that is annotated with `@PlatformRelated` or is it just this one?

Comment: That my current implement, i created all proxy beans and use AOP to invoke different implement by key parameter.But i think it isn't elegant enough.

Comment: Did you think of implementing provider class that would have a method that accepts this key parameter and based on it returns specific implementation? Creating proxies seem like an overkill to me in this case.

Comment: You could also make a usage of chain of responsibility design pattern here.

Comment: What i want is a auto create proxy mechanism, which could make me only need to implement the interface and do nothing others, when i create a new @PlateformRelated interface.

Comment: I want to create proxies by reflection and put them into spring context then set them to be @Priority at beginning of spring initialization.But i don't know how to do it.

Comment: You mean one single proxy that will delegate to specific implementation of an interface besed on key parameter? This proxy should be then autowired wherever there is need for a bean implementing the interface - is that correct?

Comment: Each interface bind to a specific proxy, this proxy be autowired wherever there is need.Business service just use this proxy, not care about what kind of implement is invoked.

Comment: I could use reflection and InvokeHandler to create proxy bean, in invokeHandler i could get key parameter then use it to find right implement then invoke it.I could use AutowireCapableBeanFactory to inject my proxy to spring context.But i don't know how to change it to be priority, which could make this proxy be autowired wherever there is need.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I must admit I haven't totally understood the meaning @Priority, however, I can say that if you want to implement this feature in spring, you should probably take a look at Bean Post Processors.

BeanPostProcessors are essentially a hook to Bean Creation process in spring intended for altering bean behavior.
Among other things, they allow wrapping the underlying bean into the proxy (CGLIB/java.lang.Proxy if you're working with interfaces, or even using programmatically Spring AOP), these proxies can provide a hook to the method execution that can read your annotations (like mentioned @KeyParameter) and execute a code in a way similar to Aspect's code that you already make use of.

Not all bean post processor wrap the bean into the proxy. For example, if you want to implement a BPP that uses "@Autowire", you will return the same bean, just "inject" (read, put by reflection) its dependencies. On the other hand, if you want to implement with BPP @Transactional behavior, then yes, you should wrap the bean into a proxy that would take care of transaction management capabilities before and after the method execution.

It's totally ok to have a spring bean that gets "altered" by many post processors, some of them would wrap it into a proxy other will just modify-and-return the same bean, If there are many BPP-s that wrap the bean into proxy we'll get "proxy inside proxy inside proxy" (you get the idea). Each layer of proxy will handle one specific behavior.

As an example, I suggest you take a look at existing Spring postprocessors, or, for instance, a source code of the following library: [Spring Boot metering integration library](http://metrics.ryantenney.com/)

This library contains some implementations of post processors that allow metrics infrastructure integration by defining annotations on methods of Spring Beans.

Comment: I could inject my proxy by BeanPostProcessor#postProcessBeforeInitialization, but it's too late, this hook will been call after @Autowired field already been injected.

Comment: A exception will been throw, like field x in BusinessService required a single bean, but 2 were found: Implement1.class & Implement2.class.
So i have to annotate Primary to anyone of my implement, or use Qualifier to identify the bean that should been consumed.I don't want to do these.Is these a hook in spring called after bean was instanced and Autowired not begin, which i could inject my proxy in and maybe remove Autowired, make spring skip this field?

Comment: Or maybe i could rewrite spring's @Autowired implement, if this field's type is annotated PlatformRelated i put my proxy in, otherwise use spring's default implement, i don't know how to do it.

Comment: there are 2 methods in BPP interface. one is'beforeInitialization' here the object has only been created but not initialized yet, it's fields are nulls for field injection. the second method is after initialization, here you already have an object ready-to-go. Put a breakpoint in a second method and you'll see that autowiring has already happened. in general you even can get proxy of the object here if your BPP is not the only one applicable to the bean. so probably you can create a proxy of the autowired bean and no need to re-implement autowiring/initialization

Comment: I found that if a interface has more than one implement and without Priority and Qualifier, some IDE will show code inspection issue. That's uncomfortable. So i use @Priority annotation for Implement1 and replace spring's injection to my proxy at BeanPostProcessor.